Is there a way to make in-app update for Android without a test account login?
I'm currently in the process of migrating from AppCenter to Firebase as the distribution platform for our Android application. This application has been distributed via AppCenter for many years. Initially, the app is manually installed by an admin, and then the Android device is handed over to the end-user. App updates are currently managed through AppCenter's in-app update API.
As part of the migration, the final release made via AppCenter includes the Firebase SDK to facilitate in-app updates through Firebase instead of AppCenter. However, I'm encountering an issue:
The Firebase in-app update API requires users to log in with a Google/test account to check for updates. With over 10,000 devices in use, this requirement poses a significant challenge, as it would need the admins to manually login on each device.
Questions:
How can I streamline the transition from AppCenter to Firebase without requiring each user to log in manually?
Is there a way to automate the login process or bypass the login requirement for the update check?
Are there alternative solutions or best practices for handling such a large-scale migration with minimal disruption to end-users and admins?
What I've tried so far:
I've enabled and using the App Distribution API and followed their documentation.
Following code will fail with FirebaseAppDistributionException: Tester is not signed in
FirebaseAppDistribution.getInstance()
                .checkForNewRelease()
                .addOnSuccessListener { release ->
                    Log.d(TAG, "Success: $release")
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                    Log.d(TAG, "failed: $e")
                }

If I make a FirebaseAppDistribution.getInstance().updateIfNewReleaseAvailable() I get the default alert asking me to "Enable testing features" then to log in with my test account.
